# Name and meaning of $\bigotimes$ in matrix operation

Tags: matrices, operator-algebras, block-matrices

Im trying to understand an operation in a paper of Statitstics. In simplified terms, the operation is :

$$A = \bigotimes_{j=1}^J \begin{bmatrix} a_j \\ b_j \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\begin{bmatrix} a_j \\ b_j \end{bmatrix}$ denotes a matrix with $a_j,b_j \in \mathbb{R}$ and $J \in \mathbb{N}$.

What is the meaning of $\bigotimes_{j=1}^J$ operator (and, for curiosity, how it is called)?

For example, if $J=3$, what is resulting matrix $A$?

Comment: It seems is related, but i couldn't make the connection with my question. So, please, if someone can clarify with an example, i will appreciate.

Comment: Have you seen the examples in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) link (answer by MathLearner)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @DietrichBurde. I see now. So, in my case with J=3, the resulting matrix have dimension $1\times 8$? That's correct?

Comment: @RenatoFernandes That is correct